# Ranking Values in Multidimensional PHP Array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I've set-up a multidimensional PHP array from a SQL query which pulls back parcels despatched per item on a daily basis.

e.g.

Item|Day1|Day2 |Day3|Day4|Day5
1   |100 | 120 | 90 |150 |60
2   |150 | 200 | 80 |90  |100
3   | 1  |  2  | 3  | 4  | 5

I want to be able to assign a ranked value to each day based upon the amount of items sent out each day and put that either into the existing array, or create a new array to which it can reference

e.g.  Item 1 Day 1 = 2, Item 2 Day 1 = 1, Item 3 Day 1 = 3, Item 1 Day 2 = 2 etc etc

I'm new to working with arrays, can anyone recommend a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you not add an ORDER BY in your query in order to do this for you?  That said, this does depend on your database design.

Otherwise if you must do it in the PHP side, you could always make a list one for each day, and when you read the information in from the database you could place it where it belongs.  This process will be slower than if you use the database.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It is a singular query, so can't do an order by within that..  Im not sure what you mean by a list for each day?

Comment: Can you show us what your sql query looks like? Give us a code snippet of what you're currently doing.